# Graphviz not printing output graph on Colab

Tags: python, graphviz, google-colaboratory, pygraphviz

I am trying Graphviz examples on Google Colab.

This is the code I am trying:

```
from graphviz import Graph

g = Graph('G', filename='process.gv', engine='sfdp')

g.edge('run', 'intr')
g.edge('intr', 'runbl')
g.edge('runbl', 'run')
g.edge('run', 'kernel')
g.edge('kernel', 'zombie')
g.edge('kernel', 'sleep')
g.edge('kernel', 'runmem')
g.edge('sleep', 'swap')
g.edge('swap', 'runswap')
g.edge('runswap', 'new')
g.edge('runswap', 'runmem')
g.edge('new', 'runmem')
g.edge('sleep', 'runmem')

g.view()
```

from https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#hello-py

I am expecting a node & edge graph as an output. However, I only get `'hello.gv.pdf'`and it doesn't draw any graph.

How can I fix this problem? I tried re-installing Graphviz on Colab but it still doesn't work

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this:

```
with open("process.gv") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

Then you will be able to observe in the google colab.

[image: result]

Or instead of `g.view()` just write `g`

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer ! Sorry for the late reply

Comment: `graphviz.Source(g)` does it. `g` produces a different output. Same graph but different shape.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: Even I was wondering the same but got my answer today. look at this doc: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/xflr6/graphviz/blob/master/examples/graphviz-engines.ipynb

Comment: Issue raised: https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/issues/134