# Cannot see the output on Google colab when I use pygraphviz

Tags: google-colaboratory, pygraphviz

I have the following code using pygraphviz on Google colab. How do I see the output graph? This is similar to [this question][1], except for the fact that the solution only works for graphviz, and not pygraphviz.

````
import pygraphviz as pgz


def tocolor(u):
    assert u >= 0
    assert u <= 1
    z = int((1-u)*256)
    return '#%2x%2x%2x'%(z,z,z)
    #return '#%2x%2x%2x'%(int(u*256),100,int((1-u)*256))

def drawG(filename,nodes,c,directed=False):
    n = len(nodes)
    G = pgz.AGraph(strict=True, directed=directed)
    G.node_attr['shape']='circle'
    #G.node_attr['style']='filled'

    for x in range(n):
        #G.add_node(nodes[x],fillcolor=".6 .1 .1")
        G.add_node(nodes[x])
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if c[i,j] < 1e-3:
                continue
            else:
                u = c[i,j]/100
                G.add_edge(nodes[i],nodes[j],color=tocolor(u),style="setlinewidth(4)")

    G.draw(filename,prog='circo',args='-Gsize="200,200"')

l='Cervix,Vagina,Uterus,Iliac LN,Mandibular LN,Mesenteric LN,Axillary LN,Bronchial LN,Colonic LN,Colon,Spleen,Rectum,Inguinal,Liver,Ovary,Bone Marrow'
l = l.split(',')
y = pylab.loadtxt('Matrix.csv',dtype=float,usecols=list(range(1,17)),delimiter=',')

def main():
    drawG('example-graph.pdf',l,y)

main() ```


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560168/graphviz-not-printing-output-graph-on-colab
````

Answer (score 1):

This import seems to be missing.

```
import pylab
```

but other than than, what error are you getting?